# Get Slack User Token for Slack API

Tags: slack-api

I'm writing a script that posts automated messages as me. I having a hard time finding my user token. Do I have to create an app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you have to create an app in order to generate a user token. You can create an app from here: https://api.slack.com/apps. Then you add the necessary scopes like `chat:write`, `groups:history` (in case of a private channel), and `groups:read` (in case of a private channel) from the OAuth & Permissions page and install the app. After you install the app, you will find your user token starting with `xoxp-` on the OAuth & Permissions page.

Comment: I can only see xoxb (BOT token) cannot find xoxp token there

Comment: If you haven't explicitly added scopes to your user token (xoxp) on the OAuth & Permissions page then you won't have that token. Or you might've added the scopes but forgotten to re-install the app?

Comment: An update to @sandra's reply, as the interface may have changed: You must add scopes to the "User Token Scopes" section and the user token will appear automatically once the app is re-installed.

Comment: i have the answer! https://i.imgur.com/ZmNGC4u.png but https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew has hid it and disabled comments on it!