# Slack oauth bot permissions for `conversations.create` when team channel management limits creation to admins only

Tags: slack-api

My app has the following scopes:

```
      - app_mentions:read
      - channels:history
      - channels:join
      - channels:manage
      - channels:read
      - chat:write
      - chat:write.public
      - commands
      - groups:write
      - pins:read
      - reactions:write
      - users:read
      - users:read.email
```

However, when calling `conversations.create` I get `restricted_action`.

Our team channel has the following setting: `People who can create public channels: "Workspace admins and owners only"`

Is there anything we can do to enable the bot user to create public channels, but maintain this setting?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Bot users can not create channels while those settings are enabled. It's also not possible to make bot users (xoxb) admins. If you're an admin or are able to authenticate your app with a admin's token than you could use that `xoxp` token to create a channel.

Comment: [link1](https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67793807) about User and Bot token